# Risks and benefits of a modified closure table for hierarchical data

Tags: sql, hierarchy

I am attempting to store hierarchical data in SQL and have resolved to use

- an object table, where all of the main data will be
- and a closure table, defining the relationships between the objects ([read more on closure tables here [slides 40 to 68]](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)).

After quite a bit of research, a closure table seemed to suit my needs well.  One thing that I kept reading, however, is that if you want to query the direct ancestor / descendant of a particular node - then you can use a `depth` column in your closure table (see slide 68 from the above link).  I have a need for this `depth` column to facilitate this exact type of query.  This is all well and good, but one of the main attractions to the closure table in the first place was the ease by which one could *both* query and modify data contained there in.  And adding a `depth` column seems to complete destroy the ease by which one can modify data (imagine adding a new node and offsetting an entire branch of the tree).

So - I'm considering modifying my closure table to define relations ***only between a node and its immediate ancestor / descendant***.  This allows me to still easily traverse the tree.  Querying data seems relatively easy.  Modifying data is not as easy as the original closure table without the `depth` field, but significantly easier than the one with the `depth` field.  It seems like a fair compromise (almost between a closure table and an adjacency list).

Am I overlooking something though? Am I loosing one of the key advantages of the closure table by doing it this way?  Does anyone see any inherent risks in doing it this way that may come to haunt me later?

Comment: So instead of having two columns in the Closure table (Ancestor and Descendant), you have three?  (this, Ancestor, Descendant)?  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @kristianp Nope.  Still two, but usually in the closure table, for each node, *all* of its ancestor / descendant relations (including distant ancestor / descendants).  Here, I'm proposing to only define the immediate relations.

Comment: It seems to me that's equivalent to an adjacency list, and as @ATrimeloni stated, you'd basically loose the advantage of using a closure table by doing that.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the key advantage you are losing is that if you want to know all of the descendants or ancestors of a node, you now have to do a lot more traversals.

For example, if you start with the following simple tree:
  A->B->C->D

To get all descendants of A you have to go A->B then B->C then C->D.   So, three queries, as opposed to a single query if following the normal pattern.